# Filtering products by category on custom cms page

Tags: product, cms, list

Could someone somehow guide me on how I can make the product list filter by clicking on one of the three buttons.

I have a custom page, and on it 3 buttons with categories. E.g. category A, B and C.

By default, products from category A should be displayed, and by clicking on these buttons I would like to change products to products from other categories.

The whole thing is done in phtml, and single block file. For displaying the products I used $productCollectionFactory, and simple for loop in phtml.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply put parameter to those button and receive them on submission

then check for the parameter value before loading it and set a default value ,something like

```
$catalog_ids = [1, 2, 3];
```

and then filter them in collection

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids));
```

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but I work in Magento more on the front-end side. So all I need to do is make a form in phtml, and pass a parameter during submit, and I can somehow receive it in block?

Comment: yes , you can receive form values with 

$this->getRequest()->getParam('filedName');